# how make a 3D matrix on python with difrent size of last parameter

Tags: python, algorithm, list, matrix

i want to make a 3D matrix in python
 but the last parameter of it should be r[i] which it is length of other vectors (and for each i they are different)
is there a way to have a matrix or list like that?

```
beta= [[[0 for col in range(Time)]for row in range(Nodes)] for x in range(r[i])]
```

this code works to make 3d matrix but i should give it all parameters .

Comment: Could you add an example of what you expect? Where does the i come from?

Comment: well to make it easier ,imagine i have them all in an 1D array    'r=[1,5,8,2,2,4,5]'

Comment: hey someone just send me an answer and it works!bet he deleted it!

Comment: Maybe it is easier when you use "normal" nested for loops and use the append method. In the outer one you iterate over the `r` array.

Comment: @UliSotschok yes ! i didnt know it is valid in python. thanks.if you want send it as an answer then i can check it as true answer .i think this will work!   ' beta = []

for i in r:
    B.append([[0 for col in range(T)] for row in range(N)])    '

Answer (score 2):

Nest it inside a "normal" for loop. This is the code as you posted it, but I don't think it produces the expected result.

```
beta = [] 
# first dimension
for i in r:    
    beta.append([[0 for col in range(Time)] for row in range(Nodes)])
                 # third dimension                second dimension
```

Some stuff to think about:

- You shouldn't start your variables name with a capital letter [pep-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-and-variable-names)
- I think you want to use the `i` variable somehow inside the loop.